# Surround an element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wish surround an `<a>` with `<h1></h1>`. I'm trying :

```
<a class="toto">TEST</a>
```

```js
var test = $('.toto');
test.before('<h2>');
test.after('</h2>');
```

However it does not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code doesn't work as you can only append whole elements to the DOM. The output of what you're trying would be this:

```
<h2></h2>
<a class="toto">TEST</a>
<h2></h2>
```

To do what you require, use `wrap()`:

```js
$('.toto').wrap('<h2 />'); // or .wrap('<h1 />');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="toto">TEST</a>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.